# Get a variable from the URL in a Flask route

Tags: python, url, flask

I have a number of URLs that start with `landingpage` and end with a unique id.  I need to be able to get the id from the URL, so that I can pass some data from another system to my Flask app.  How can I get this value?

```
http://localhost/landingpageA
http://localhost/landingpageB
http://localhost/landingpageC
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This is answered in the [quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/#variable-rules) of the docs.

You want a variable URL, which you create by adding `<name>` placeholders in the URL and accepting corresponding `name` arguments in the view function.

```
@app.route('/landingpage<id>')  # /landingpageA
def landing_page(id):
    ...
```

More typically the parts of a URL are separated with `/`.

```
@app.route('/landingpage/<id>')  # /landingpage/A
def landing_page(id):
    ...
```

Use `url_for` to generate the URLs to the pages.

```
url_for('landing_page', id='A')
# /landingpage/A
```

You could also pass the value as part of the query string, and [get it from the request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/#the-request-object), although if it's always required it's better to use the variable like above.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/landingpage')
def landing_page():
    id = request.args['id']
    ...

# /landingpage?id=A
```

Answer (score 8):

like this  the example

```py
@app.route('/profile/<username>')
def lihat_profile(username):
    return "welcome to profile page %s" % username
```