# Adding a variable in a React backend

Tags: python, flask

I am created a React as a backend to an application I am writing but I am getting an error that I can't figure out how to fix after looking at the docs

Here is my code (simplified)

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/one_hit/<band>',methods=["GET"])
def one_hit(band):
   //Code Here
   return output
```

and get the following error "TypeError: one_hit() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)" when I run the "flask run" command

According to https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/ I just need the  section. Am I reading it wrong or is there something I am missing?

Comment: Why do you mentioned "React backend" here? How exactly did you make your GET request to that endpoint? It's expecting a parameter `band`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a variable from the URL in a Flask route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188540/get-a-variable-from-the-url-in-a-flask-route)

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code, I have made some changes:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/one-hit/<string:band>',methods=["GET"])
def one_hit(band):
   return {"result": band}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=28990)
```

And also run the application using the following command

```
python filename.py
```