# creating temporary webpages using python for my website

Tags: python, sockets, http, websocket

I have a website with nothing on it and I am trying to create a python program that someone can launch, and create a temporary page on my website, so for example my website is example.com and it would create website.com/aw34ed with a random url extension, and if someone were to enter the temporary webpage it would send data to the python program where ever that person is running it. I would also like the temporary website extension/page to delete itself and not exist after a certain amount of time.

I understand this question is kind of vague so am I kind of wondering what I would use to do this and how difficult this would be to create

Comment: You want to make a webserver in python. And then you can respond to http requests from browsers *however you want* - such as making a connection to someone else's python program. There are many different ways to make a webserver run python code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flask variables (as this answer states: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63839730/15447633).

```py
@app.route('/temp/<id>')
def show_temp_page(id):
    # some method for getting the temporary page, perhaps a db lookup
```