# Check if string contains user-defined substring using SQL LIKE operator

Tags: sql

Basically I have a table like this:

| movieId | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | White chicks |
| 2 | Inception |
| 3 | The Avengers: Endgame |
| 4 | Avatar: The Last Air Bender |

My job is to retrieve all relevant movies based on a substring of the movie name. For example, if a user enters a substring such as "av" (e.g., they enter "http://localhost:5000/search/movies?name=av"), they will find movies like The Avengers and Avatar.

Because the assignment requires the use of a Model-View-Controller(MVC) design with a pool of open connections, I have created 3 separate python files (a model, a controller and a database). For full information, this is my database file (shown below):

```
from mysql.connector import pooling

class DatabasePool:
    connection_pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
                               pool_name="ws_pool",
                               pool_size=5,
                               host='localhost'
                               database='assignment',
                               user='root',
                               password='abc123')

    @classmethod
    def getConnection(cls):
        dbConn = cls.connection_pool.get_connection()
        return dbConn
```

This is my model file (shown below):

```
from model.DatabasePool import DatabasePool

class Movie:
    @classmethod
    def getRelevantMovies(cls,name):
        try:
            dbConn = DatabasePool.getConnection()
            cursor = dbConn.cursor(dictionary=True)
            sql = "select * from movie where name like % + %s + %"
            cursor.execute(sql,(name,))
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            return results
        finally:
            dbConn.close()
```

and this is my controller file (shown below):

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request
from model.Movie import Movie

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/search/movies', methods=['GET'])

def getMoviesBySubstring(name):
    try:
        movieList = Movie.getRelevantMovies(name)

        if len(movieList)>0:
            foundData = {"Movies":movieList}
            return jsonify(foundData),200

        else:
            return jsonify({}),400

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        return jsonify({}),500

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am struggling to figure out how exactly can I modify the sql code (found in the model file) to take in whatever substring input entered by the user (e.g., http://localhost:5000/search/movies?name=av), select the relevant movies in the database (Avatar and The Avengers) and pass it back to the controller. I am only allowed to use the like operator. Most online guides (e.g., [Check if a string contains a substring in SQL Server 2005, using a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505923/check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-sql-server-2005-using-a-stored-proced)) on the LIKE operator have given examples that require pre-specified queries (e.g., using %a% to find values that contain an "a"), which is not appropriate for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it! You owe me a drink... really! :-)

Beforehand, I named `main.py` because I don't do Flask (but, yes, I tested it!).

In:

- `model/DatabasePool.py`, you had a missing comma @7
- `model/Movie.py`, the query had to be changed
- `main.py`, Flask controllers do not expect as call parameters those from URLs as `?parm=val`

### model/DatabasePool.py

```
from mysql.connector import pooling

class DatabasePool:
    connection_pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
                               pool_name="ws_pool",
                               pool_size=5,
                               host='localhost',
                               database='assignment',
                               user='root', 
                               password='abc123')

    @classmethod
    def getConnection(cls):
        dbConn = cls.connection_pool.get_connection()
        return dbConn
```

### model/Movie.py

```
class Movie:
    @classmethod
    def getRelevantMovies(cls,name):
        try:
            dbConn = DatabasePool.getConnection()
            cursor = dbConn.cursor(dictionary=True)
            sql = "select * from movie where name like %s"
            cursor.execute(sql, (f"%{name}%", ))
            results = cursor.fetchall()
            return results
        finally:
            dbConn.close()
```

### main.py

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request
from model.Movie import Movie

app = Flask(__name__)

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/35189294/206413
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/51385027/206413
@app.route('/search/movies', methods=['GET'])
def getMoviesBySubstring():
    name = request.args['name']

    try:
        movieList = Movie.getRelevantMovies(name)

        if len(movieList)>0:
            foundData = {"Movies":movieList}
            return jsonify(foundData),200

        else:
            return jsonify({}),400

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        return jsonify({}),500

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Oh. One more thing! Man, Python is awesome, but it's not built for web apps. React, Vue, .Net, Ruby/Rails are perfect alternatives.

---

#### Depricated

---

You are almost there.

I'm pretty sure these lines below yield an exception, right?

```
sql = "select * from movie where name like % + %s + %"
cursor.execute(sql,(name,))
```

Change them to:

```
sql = "select * from movie where name like %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (f"%{name}%", ))
```

I don't have a working environment here to check it. So... my apologies if it's syntactic wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Doesn't seem to work for me, I've tried solutions from both Vignesh and your's. Both return TypeError: getMoviesBySubstring() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'.  Nonetheless, really appreciate this

Comment: @Ebbinghaus, `... missing 1 required argument...` has nothing to do with the `like` clause. Are you sure the code in your question is up-to-date?

Comment: I gave my codes a second check (even re-wrote the entire thing) but still encounter the same error. I suspect the issue is with the control file (because the error kept referring to getMoviesBySubstring()) but it doesnt make sense to instantiate the movie class either. Please let me know if you need any further information!

Comment: @Ebbinghaus, please, try this edited solution. Lemme know the results, ok?

Comment: Marcus Vinicius Pompeu (still awaiting the day when the stack grants me @ powers) I just want to say thank you so much for your help! You have freed me from another week of suffering and I now see the importance of request.args. I definitely owe you several drinks :)   Also, for learning's sake, may I know where can I learn more about this "f"%{name}%""? Thank you once again!

Comment: @Ebbinghaus, the name is `f-string syntax`. Enjoy! https://www.google.com/search?q=python+f-string

Answer (score 0):

Use the below SQL statement:

```
sql = "select * from movie where name like %%{0}%%".format(name)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: this is SQL Injection 101 :-)